# localstorage for login[reactjs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a button that, when clicked, should say `WELCOME USER`. Additionally, I want to store whether the user has clicked the button in `localStorage` so on subsequent page loads I can tell if they've clicked the button. If the user *hasn't* yet clicked the button and the value is not set in local storage, we should *not* show the text `WELCOME USER`.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App(){
  let [isLogin,setIsLoging] = useState(false)
  localStorage.setItem("isLogin",false)

  if (localStorage.getItem("isLogin") == "true") {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Welcome user</h1>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={login}>login</button>
      </>
    );
  }

  function login(){
    setIsLoging(isLogin = true)
    localStorage.setItem("isLogin", true)
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I miss understood what u wan't sorry try this

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isLogin, setIsLoging] = useState(localStorage.isLogin ? true : false);
  return (
    <>
      {isLogin ? (
        <h1>Welcome User </h1>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={login}>login</button>
      )}
    </>
  );
  function login() {
    setIsLoging(true);
    if(!localStorage.isLogin)
      localStorage.isLogin = true;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: This will not persist login state though

Comment: I see. so he want the user to stay logged even when the page refresh, i will edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the setter of useState wrong. It should be `setIsLogin(true)`. Also you are setting the value false on the beginning of every render cycle, so it will never be true... You should be putting calls to localStorage into a useEffect, to not do it on every rerender.